# Merge and paste duplicate columns in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have two data frames with some common variable `x`:

```
df1 <- data.frame( 
  x=c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
  y=c("a", "b", "c", "d") 
)

df2 <- data.frame( 
  x=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
  z=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G") 
)
```

We can assume that each entry of the variable we're merging over, `x`, appears exactly once in `df1`; however, it may appear an arbitrary number of times in `df2`.

I want to merge `df2` 'into' `df1`, while preserving `df1`. Is there a fast way of merging these two data frames such that the merged output would be of the form (for example):

```
df_merged <- data.frame( 
  x=c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
  y=c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
  z=c("A B", "C D", "E", "F")
)
```

Essentially, I want `df_merged` to be a composition of the original `df1`, in addition to any variables in `df2` coerced to match the format of `df1`. The various incantations of `merge` will append new rows to the merged output, which I want to avoid.

We can assume that each entry of the variable we're merging over, `x`, appears exactly once.

Speed is also a priority since I'll be merging fairly large data frames.

Answer (score 1):

```
merge( df1, 
       aggregate(df2$z , df2[1], FUN=paste, collapse=" ", sep=""), 
       by.x="x", by.y=1)
  x y   x
1 1 a A B
2 2 b C D
3 3 c   E
4 4 d   F
Warning message:
In merge.data.frame(df1, aggregate(df2$z, df2[1], FUN = paste, collapse = " ",  :
  column name ‘x’ is duplicated in the result
> M1 <- .Last.value
> names(M1)[3] <- "z"
> M1
  x y   z
1 1 a A B
2 2 b C D
3 3 c   E
4 4 d   F
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
df2.z <- with(df2, tapply(z, x, paste, collapse=' '))
transform(df1, z=df2.z[match(x, names(df2.z))])

#   x y   z
# 1 1 a A B
# 2 2 b C D
# 3 3 c   E
# 4 4 d   F
```

If `df1$x` is in order, then use `df2.z[names(df2.z) %in% x]` in the transform statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm submitting this question with my own potential answer, but it is fairly slow and I'm curious what other methods might be available.

```
by <- "x"
df2_processed <- as.data.frame( 
    sapply( names(df2), function(x) {
      tapply( df2[[x]], df2[[by]], function(xx) {
        if( x == by ) {
          return(xx[1])
        } else {
          paste(xx, collapse=" ")
        }
      })
    }), optional=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE )

merge( df1, df2_processed, all.x=TRUE )
```